# Viewpager can only be swiped from the edge of the screen

Tags: android, android-viewpager, gesture

I have implemented two viewpagers, one viewpager from android for swiping horizontally left and right fragments. and second is custom vertical viewpager within the fragment to swipe image up and down. i can swipe vertically any where, but i cannot swipe viewpager horizontally. horizontal viewpager can only be swiped from the edge of the screen. how to make the horizontal viewpager can be swiped horizontally anywhere?

here is my custom vertical viewpager.

```
public class VerticalViewPager extends ViewPager {
public VerticalViewPager(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public VerticalViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    // The majority of the magic happens here
    setPageTransformer(true, new VerticalPageTransformer());
    // The easiest way to get rid of the overscroll drawing that happens on the left and right
    setOverScrollMode(OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
}

private class VerticalPageTransformer implements ViewPager.PageTransformer {

    @Override
    public void transformPage(View view, float position) {

        if (position < -1) { // [-Infinity,-1)
            // This page is way off-screen to the left.
            view.setAlpha(0);

        } else if (position <= 1) { // [-1,1]
            view.setAlpha(1);

            // Counteract the default slide transition
            view.setTranslationX(view.getWidth() * -position);

            //set Y position to swipe in from top
            float yPosition = position * view.getHeight();
            view.setTranslationY(yPosition);

        } else { // (1,+Infinity]
            // This page is way off-screen to the right.
            view.setAlpha(0);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Swaps the X and Y coordinates of your touch event.
 */
private MotionEvent swapXY(MotionEvent ev) {
    float width = getWidth();
    float height = getHeight();

    float newX = (ev.getY() / height) * width;
    float newY = (ev.getX() / width) * height;

    ev.setLocation(newX, newY);

    return ev;
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev){
    boolean intercepted = super.onInterceptTouchEvent(swapXY(ev));
    swapXY(ev); // return touch coordinates to original reference frame for any child views
    return intercepted;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    return super.onTouchEvent(swapXY(ev));
}}
```

Answer (score 3):

Override canScrollHorizontally in your VerticalViewPager :

```
@Override
public boolean canScrollHorizontally(int direction) {
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try [this Link](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1863)

It have the feature of both Horizontal + Vertical ViewPager at the same time. You can download sample code from [here](https://github.com/juliome10/DoubleViewPager/tree/master/DoubleViewPagerSample)

Comment: thank you for the answer. i have been trying using this library in my project.

Comment: You welcome. If this library work please accept and up vote answer.